# Tkinter window closes during runtime

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script and a text file that contains a list of times (string) like 18:59, 19:00, 19:02, etc... each in a different line. I want to change the color of a label in tkinter whenever the time in the file is the current time.

The problem is the tkinter window closes once it opens and then opens again once everything is complete. I tried using update_idletasks. But that did not change anything. Here is the required code structure:

```
class gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, txt2, index):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent,background="white")
    self.parent = parent
    self.txt2 = txt2
    self.index = index
    self.initUI()
    self.initChange()

def initUI(self)
    #initial window with white color label

def initChange(self)
    while(last line hasnt reached):
        if(current time = file time)
            #line for changing label color and self.index++
            self.parent.update_idletasks()
        sleep(30) 

main()
    #call all the functions required and root, txt file and initial index is passed as arguments for gui functions
```

Since I was requested to put up all the functions i have used, I am doing so but I am omitting out the details. The code is too long.

```
def dataextract(xlsheet):
    #take data from xlsheet
    #called only once in the main() function

def fileio(x, txt1)
    #Write the time list after doing some operations
    #based on data from xlsheet

def main():
    x = datextract(xlsheet)
    fileio(x, txt)
    print "File IO competed..."
    root = Tk()
    app = gui(root, txt2, 0)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is `main()`? And all the functions/lines being missed out. We cannot help without seeing those.

Comment: Do you have a `mainloop`?

Comment: @Pythonista yes i do

Comment: Then post main and other relevant code

Comment: Why are you calling `sleep`? That puts everything to sleep, including the Tkinter mainloop, so events can't be processed and the GUI cannot be updated. Take a look at the widget `.after` method.

Comment: @PM2Ring if i dont call sleep, then the loop will check for every second all the time. Isnt this inefficient?

Comment: @PM2Ring i removed the sleep command. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

After going through many posts in stack overflow and a lot of other websites, I got my app working fine. The problem is, python was running on a single thread. The tkinter window is initially allocated a thread and when initChange is called, the thread is now taken away from tkinter. All I had to do was call initChange in a separate thread. To do so,

```
class gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, txt2, index):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent,background="white")
    self.parent = parent
    self.txt2 = txt2
    self.index = index
    self.initUI()
    thread.start_new_thread(self.initChange,())
```

But there is a small problem here. There is a slight delay since my while loop keeps checking every second if the specified time has reached. It would be really helpful if someone can suggest some improvements.